# Using SQL, how do I update rows, using their own values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table which I'll call 'example'

```
id name       last_name
01 Adam       Adams
02 Bill       Billo
03 Cathy      McCathyson
```

I need to modify the table and end up with the following:

```
id name
01 Adam Adams
02 Bill Billo
03 Cathy McCathyson
```

For a single row, I know how to write this query:

```
UPDATE example SET name = 
   (SELECT name FROM example WHERE id = 01)+" "
   +(SELECT last_name FROM example WHERE id = 01)
WHERE id = 01;
```

How do I modify this query such that it updates each row with that row's values, as in the example?

**EDIT:**  I've updated my example since it confused the issue.

Comment: You mean you want to embed the HTML in the DB data? Why?

Comment: This is a good example why it is a bad idea to embed html in the database. You would have been better off storing the color and generating the html in the application.

Comment: Any reason for the change in test data ?

Comment: @Sathya Sorry!  My example was a poor choice.  Using HTML in the example data was causing people to focus on that, rather than the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UPDATE example SET NAME = NAME + ' ' + last_name
```

---

```
    ID NAME      LAST_NAME
```

---

```
     1 Adam       Adams
     2 Bill       Billo
     3 Cathy      McCathyson

SQL> UPDATE example SET NAME = NAME + ' ' + last_name
  2  /

3 rows updated

SQL> select * from example
  2  /

        ID NAME                    LAST_NAME
---------- -----------------------------------------
         1 Adam Adams              Adams
         2 Bill Billo              Billo
         3 Cathy McCathyson        McCathyson
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to consider adding this as a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx). That way the column is virtual, so you're not using extra storage space. Also, any changes to name or last_name are automatically reflected in the new column without any intervention.

**EDIT**: Modified code based on change in example.

```
alter table example
    add full_name as coalesce(name+' ','') + last_name
```

Comment: +1 for computed column - Not normally a good idea to edit your original data for an aesthetic change :)

Comment: +1 Without a computed column, you lose the original first/last split.  There is no going back!

Comment: +1 because this is something awesome that I did not know about.  With my actual data, I do need to combine and eliminate though, so I'm sorry I did not choose this answer.  Thanks though, Joe!

Answer (score 4):

**NB: This answer was based on the first incarnation of the question. The same general principles apply to the revised version so I haven't updated the column names to keep in synch.**

@n8wrl raises a good question in the comments but to answer your question (assuming that color and text are both character data and so do not need any casting).

Also I have assumed that non of the columns are nullable. If they are then concatenating `NULL` will yield `NULL` assuming you have ANSI default options. If that is not the desired behaviour you would need to use `ISNULL(color,'')` etc.

```
DECLARE @example  table 
(
id int NOT NULL,
color char(6) NOT NULL,
text varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
insert into @example
SELECT 01, '990000',   'Red' UNION ALL
SELECT 02, '009900',   'Green' UNION ALL
SELECT 03, '000099',   'Blue'

UPDATE @example SET text = '<span style=''color: #'
   +color+'''>'
   +text+'</span>'
/*WHERE id = 01;*/

SELECT * FROM @example
```

I have to say that I doubt that storing it in this format is a good idea. It means that you will be storing a lot of redundant characters which means less rows will fit on a data page and greater I/O and less efficient use of memory

Comment: This only works for the row with id of 01.  Are you saying that if I take off the WHERE clause, it will work for every row?

Comment: If you're trying to do the whole table, the `WHERE` clause is not needed.

Comment: Change your WHERE to any condition and it will happen for any rows that meet the criteria - all rows if no WHERE included.

Comment: @BigDave - Yes. See edit for a demo without the `where` clause. I have to say that I doubt that storing it in this format is a good idea though...